Получить значение из вложенной генераторной функции, возвращённое с помощью оператора "return"
Вот мой код:
def gen_middle():
    def gen_nested():
        counter = 0
        while True:
            yield counter
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 2:
                return 'My special value'

    yield from gen_nested()

def main():
    iterator = iter(gen_middle())
    
    try:
        while True:
            value = next(iterator)
            print(value)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        # returned value (with "return") from gen_nested was expected
        print(exc.value)

main()

Я ожидал вывод:
0
1
My special value

Но получил:
0
1
None

В связи с этим у меня два вопроса.

Оператор yield from не эскалирует исключение StopIteration со значением из вложенного генератора?
Могу ли я получить это значение ('My special value') не меняя код функций gen_middle и gen_nested?


1 - нет. Высокоуровневые конструкции (итерация через for, yield from) скрывают от нас детали, в том числе наличие исключения StopIteration. 2 - нет. Нужно менять yield from на цикл while, отлавливать StopIteration, точно так же, как вы это делаете снаружи.

Как вариант - сделать свой класс-итератор, который "специальное значение" записывает в свое поле. Либо класс-обертку, который StopIteration будет отлавливать и сохранять в свое поле.

Не меняя gen_middle - нет, потому, что она получила значение от генератора и проигнорировала его. чтобы передала его дальше - return (yield from gen_nested())

Это ужасно, спасибо.

Нужно предложить PEP в связи с этим. Я перечитал связанные предложения, но так и не понял почему это не было сделано.

Это нормально. Если вам нужна полная функциональность генератора (return, send), то используете низкоуровневое api (next, StopIteration), если просто поитерироваться - то for и прочее, yield from. Вот такие случаи как у вас - это что-то очень редкое, из-за этого вряд ли будут какой-то PEP принимать. Такое скорее нужно решать на уровне архитектуры кода, а не пытаться вытащить детали низкого уровня на верхний уровень.

Вообще, тут проще бросить какое-то кастомное исключение, а на верхнем уровне отлавливать. Тогда и while-next можно будет тогда заменить на обычный for.

Все высокоуровневые итерирующие конструкции (от for до yield from) сами обрабатывают StopIteration, наружу "выходит" уже новое исключение StopIteration, а то что было брошено самым внутренним итератором со своим value наружу не выходит. Наверное, логично было бы, чтобы value пробрасывалось через всю цепочку отловленных StopIteration, но видимо это такой редкий случай (use case), что никто про это не подумал.
С другой стороны, если внутри было несколько итераторов (например, происходит склейка нескольких последовательностей значений, как в itertools.chain), то какое из значений должно пробрасываться наружу? Если последнее, то почему оно, почему должны пропасть return значения других генераторов?
Тут проще всего создать свое отдельное исключение, изнутри его выбрасывать, на самом внешнем уровне обрабатывать, тогда и внешний while-next можно заменить на обычный for (что более красиво):
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


def gen_middle():
    def gen_nested():
        counter = 0
        while True:
            yield counter
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 2:
                raise MyCustomException('My special value')

    yield from gen_nested()


def main():
    iterator = iter(gen_middle())
    
    try:
        for value in iterator:
            print(value)
    except MyCustomException as exc:
        print(exc.value)


main()


Конкретно для случая, если внутри функции ровно один yield from, можно его тупо заменить на return, чтобы просто возвращался исходный генератор:
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


def gen_middle():
    def gen_nested():
        counter = 0
        while True:
            yield counter
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 2:
                return 'My special value'

    return gen_nested()  # было yield from


def main():
    iterator = iter(gen_middle())
    
    try:
        while True:
            value = next(iterator)
            print(value)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        # returned value (with "return") from gen_nested was expected
        print(exc.value)


main()


Я согласен, что это проблема плохой архитектуры кода. Но я не нашёл, как переделать его более изящно. Я пишу генераторную функцию для обхода виртуальной файловой системы. Логика этой функции чрезвычайно сложна и разбросана по ветвящимся цепочкам корутин с кучей параметров.

Насчёт того, какой эксепшен пробрасывать из цепочки, вспомнилось, что в C# есть AggregateException, в который собирается несколько эксепшенов. Не знаю, есть ли такое в Питоне )

@Aycon тут не понятно что за значение вы возвращаете из итератора. Если это исключительная ситуация (ошибка), то вполне логично исключения использовать. Если у вас всегда что-то в конце возвращается, то тогда возможно есть смысл свой класс итератора реализовать, в котором конечное значение в поле этого кастомного итератора записывается. Но возможно придется отказаться от yield from и прочих выскоуровневых конструкций.

В моём коде (не в примере этого вопроса) я возвращаю итератор прокси объектов файловой системы из своей сложной функции обхода файловой системы с архивами различной степени вложенности и типа (в том числе с паролями). Это действительно сложная функция. Недавно мне понадобилось гарантировать распаковку глубочайшего архива с обходом регистрации на удаление временного файла. Мне было намного проще пробросить один параметр через всю цепочку корутин и обрабатывать этот случай отдельно с возвратом пути к временному файлу с помощью return, чем писать копию этой огромной функции для похожей задачи.

Это несомненно недочёт архитектуры. Я мог бы решить это с помощью паттерна стратегия, я думаю. Но лишний параметр всё равно останется, просто это будет ссылка на функцию, а не булевый флаг режима.
